# How can i pass a line number in a for loop to traverse a text file?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, text, line-numbers

I have a text file in which i want to start doing a task only after i find a keyword. But the keyword I'm searching for occurs twice in the file. I want to do the task only for the text after second keyword.

I can get the line in which my required keyword occurs second time but how do i pass this to a for loop and do my task.

Im looking for something like:

```
with open(r"myfile.txt") as openfile:
    for line in (line_number, openfile):
        #Do my task to the line
```

Where line_number has the number where I found the keyword second time

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple flag count to determine the second time the keyword is found:

```
keyword = 'A'
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    c, flag = 0, 0
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        c += 1
        print("Line {}: {}".format(c, line.strip()))
        if keyword in line:
            flag += 1
        if keyword in line and flag == 2:
            print('do some tasks')
```

Output

```
Line 1: C E
Line 2: A F
Line 3: E
Line 4: C D
Line 5: A B
do some tasks
Line 6: 1 C E
```

A better approach (same output) would be to use `enumerate`:

```
keyword = 'A'
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    flag = 0
    for c, line in enumerate(fp):
        print("Line {}: {}".format(c+1, line.strip()))   #remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
        if keyword in line:
            flag += 1
        if keyword in line and flag == 2:
            print('do some tasks')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process only the lines after the line with the second occurrence of a keyword, you should not be looking for line numbers. Instead, you can treat the file object as an iterator and use a generator expression to filter lines with the keyword and use `itertools.islice` to consume lines up to the line with the second occurrence of the keyword.

As an example, the code below skips lines until the second occurrence of the  keyword `begin`:

```
from itertools import islice

keyword='begin'
with open('myfile.txt') as openfile:
    list(islice((line for line in openfile if keyword in line), 0, 2))
    for line in openfile:
        print(line, end='')
```

so that given the content of `myfile.txt`:

```
header
begin
second header
begin
foo
bar
```

the above code would output:

```
foo
bar
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/OnlyUtterFossil